# How to run a formula until max or threshold value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-statements, max, threshold

I am searching for an answer to the question below.

I am creating individual-level life tables in excel and only need the formula to run until a max possible age of 100.

I am using the excel formula below. This, `($G7+I$6)` represents `age + time period`. Stating the obvious, this is not the output value but rather a component of the formula.

`=EXP((-$C$2^-1)*(EXP($C$3+($D7*$F$2)+($C7*$F$3)+($B7*$F$4)))*(EXP($C$2*($G7+I$6))-1))`

Once again, I need the formula to run until `($G7+I$6)` reaches 100. So the formula should stop once `($G7+I$6)` reaches 100.

How do I do this?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Jay

Answer (score 0):

Why not wrap the entire formula in an IF Statement where =IF(($G7+I$6)>=100,Error Condition or let you know,EXP((-$C$2^-1)*(EXP($C$3+($D7*$F$2)+($C7*$F$3)+($B7*$F$4)))*(EXP($C$2*($G7+I$6))-1))

Comment: Hi Saket, thanks for the help. How would this be written? Is this correct? `=IF(($G7+I$6)>=100(EXP((-$C$2^-1)(EXP($C$3+($D7$F$2)+($C7*$F$3)+($B7*$F$4)))(EXP($C$2($G7+I$6))-1)))`

Comment: Hi Saket, I got it to work with this: `Excel formula: =IF(($G7+I$6)<=100,((EXP((-$C$2^-1)*(EXP($C$3+($D7*$F$2)+($C7*$F$3)+($B7*$F$4)))*(EXP($C$2*($G7+I$6))-1)))))`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As above, the solution is this:
`Excel formula: =IF(($G7+I$6)<=100,((EXP((-$C$2^-1)*(EXP($C$3+($D7*$F$2)+($C7*$F$3)+($B7*$F$4)))*(EXP($C$2*($G7+I$6))-1)))))`